# Why don't all welders use auto-darkening hoods?

Tags: welding

I'm seeing auto-darkening welding helmets selling for barely more than the price of a conventional mask.  But I also rarely see professional welders using auto-darkening hoods.  Is there a reason for that?

As an amateur welder I find it tricky to setup on a weld, drop my mask, and then strike a clean arc before I can see what I'm doing.

I'm sure a professional has no trouble with that.  But given that the cost for auto-darkening is so low, I am confused when I still see them flipping a manual hood up and down for every strike.  I'm wondering if there is some drawback to the auto-darkeners that they know about?

Comment: Please if you feel I'm out of line, we can discuss this at [The Pitstop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop). As it stands, the question is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few reasons.

Firstly the first few generations of auto lenses had several drawbacks: they were expensive, had a restricted field of vision, and in some cases didn't give such a clear view of the weld as fixed shade lenses – especially metal coated ones. This is particularly important for MMA and TIG welding where you need to be able to see the weld puddle in quite some detail to get a really good quality weld and spot defects as they arise.

The best auto lenses largely solve these problems but they are still quite expensive compared to generic ones.

Secondly if you are happy to use a fixed shade lens you will get a better view for the same money with no real drawbacks.

There is also the fact that skilled people can be a bit set in their ways and, rightly or wrongly, tend to like the system they learned on and may also see fixed shade lenses as a badge of skill.

There is also an issue with TIG especially that in some circumstances the arc doesn't always trigger the sensors, especially if you are welding at awkward angles or low current which is annoying, to say the least. Also, reflections from the metal you are welding can trigger the sensor before you are ready.

Having said that, for most welders the advantages of auto lenses far outweigh the disadvantages.

Answer (score 4):

Just because the cost of auto darkening is the same now, that hasn't always been the case.  When they were new, the tech was much more expensive.  When you're starting out and buying tools, you don't have much money, so you get the basics you can afford and build from that.

If you start with a manual hood, you're going to learn with that and get used to it, and it's something that lasts a long time.  It's what the guys teaching you are using, and you learn to like it.  Do you trust this "new high tech magic" with your eyes that you make a living with, or do you keep using what you've known for the past 10 years?  It's electronic, so its possible for it to stop working, right?  If it ever breaks, you're going to hurt your eyes or be stuck not being able to work until its replaced.  The old glass lenses never stop working.

I'm sure guys starting out today are going to be using the new helmets because of the current price, and the mature tech, but that's just not going to trickle down to the old pros quickly if ever.